# Display all authors in a theme template

Tags: author, list-authors, author-template

I was having an issue the other day and successfully got a very good answer which helped me alot achive what I wanted.
this is the post which I created and have all the correspondence:

[wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63060/display-all-authors-and-their-only-one-latest-post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63060/display-all-authors-and-their-only-one-latest-post)

The answer was kindly contributed courtesy of @Sagive SEO

This script currently displays all authors in an order of most posts written.

I would like to change it to simply display all authors randomly regardless of how many posts they wrote.

Hope to get an answer, thanks a lot
Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to shuffle all the array elements & then display them. But since php's `shuffle()` function doesn't preserve array key associations, here's a version that does.

```
function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    shuffle($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[(string)$key] = $array[$key];
    }
    $array = $new;
    return true;
}
```

Add this function somewhere in your functions.php & replace `arsort($authorsArray);` with `shuffle_assoc($authorsArray);` in the code suggested in the previous question

Comment: Works just like magic! thanks a lot @Mridul Aggarwal!