# Saving return value from the_author_posts_link()

Tags: loop, author

As you know, in the loop, `the_title()` function displays (echos) the post title to the screen, and `get_the_title()` returns it (so it can be saved in a variable). The same is true for the pair `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and `the_post_thumbnail()`.

Now, what is equivallent to `the_author_posts_link()`? I need to save that information rather than displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author posts link returns the author name which is linked to posts written by him. I think what you need is the author name of the post.

It can be retrieved with `<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>` and if in case you need the link to the posts by this author then use:

`<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>`.

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one. However there seems to be a hook with the same name "the_author_posts_link" that you should be able to use in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter('the_author_posts_link', change_link);

function change_link($link){

  // You probably want to use some regex here to change the link, or perhaps just a 
 //str_replace() depending on what you're trying to accomplish. 
 //Then you just return the $link.

 return $link;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an equivalent.

If you know the author's Id, you can probably use a new query like one of this type :

```
$author_query = new WP_Query('author='.$authorid.'&posts_per_page=-1&' );
```

However, with this kind of approach, you will still need a loop to extract all the links information. You will find more information about this kind of solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63060/display-all-authors-and-their-only-one-latest-post) (not the same question as yours but similar approach).